# X-axis and data point labels on SSRS report are incorrect

Tags: reporting-services

The X-axis should show intervals from 0-100% with 10% interval which instead is showing in 1000% to 10000%. And the bar chart should show data points in % which instead is showing 0.######. Please help on how to set this up right. I fixed the Data points by *100 and rounding up to 2 decimals but is it the right way to do it.

Comment: Solution: Remove *100 on the value axis expression. And second this is since the properties on series were not letting me change the number format to %. I had to manually add the calculation to the Label text and *100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `*100`. If you format the output as percentage then it will deal with this for you.

[image: Format as Percentage example]

- 0.1 is equal to 10%
- 1 is equal to 100%

Comment: Thank you. It did help the Xaxis but the values on the Data point are not in %. Like instead 74% it is .74.

Comment: @user3083627 using the Percentage option as per the screenshot in my answer?

Comment: @user3083627 What do you mean by Data point? Tool-tip or data label?

Comment: @user3083627 if you right click on one of your data labels --> Series Label Properties, then you should have the same Number format options. Choose percentage there also.

Comment: I tried that but everytime I click ok come out and save. It reverts back that change... Feel so weird about it.

Comment: @user3083627 that is strange... You could try setting your data label text to an expression and using `=FormatPercent(Fields!YourValue.Value,2)` (again FormatPercent will deal with *100)

Comment: Exactly that's what I finally did, had to manually add the calculation to the label text and *100 & %. Thank you very much.